# Maintain 8-bit pixel depth in Raster Calculator

Tags: python, raster, modelbuilder, arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator

Would anyone know how to maintain 8-bit pixels when computing raster calculations in ArcMap?

This is part of a model so I need to keep the image with the original 8 bit, do the calculations, convert it into 32bit and do some other calculations and then output it.

The problem is to keep it at 8 bit for the first set of calculations.